# css3 img odd & even child

Tags: html, css

I want to target the images and give the odd occurrence different rotation compare to even ones and I am using the following html and css but it does not work. Can anyone let me know what am I missing here:

```
<div id="blocks" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px; padding: 20px 0 0 20px;">

<div style="height: 150px"><p><img src="mike.jpg" align="left" class="students">
<font color="red">Mike</font>"hello from UK." 
</p></div>


<div style="height: 150px"><p><img src="jack.jpg" align="left" class="students">
<font color="red">Jack</font> 
"Hello from US"
</p></div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#blocks img:nth-child(even) {

transform:rotate(5deg);

}
#blocks img:nth-child(odd) {

transform:rotate(5deg);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this instead:

```
#blocks div:nth-child(even) img {
    /* styling */
}

#blocks div:nth-child(odd) img {
    /* styling */
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/FXm2y/)

The reason this works, is because we are targeting the (`even`/`odd`) `div` elements, as opposed the `img` elements. The reason `:nth-child` wasn't working on the `img` elements was because they weren't siblings, unlike the `div` elements.